# Should I use one HttpClient instance per request or one to handle all my requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a client for Rest API and I'm using the HttpClient class.
My question is: should I use just one instance to handle all my requests? or should I create a new instance per request? Like:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
  ...
}
```

Is there any recommended practice?

Comment: good explanation on when to reuse and when to use new HttpClient http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to reuse HttpClient instances as much as possible. The only reason to create a new instance is if you want to configure it differently.

Comment: Thanks!. Do you have any source?

Comment: I'm a developer on the WebAPI team. I double-checked for you with the right person. : )

Comment: How about a link to an example that shows how best to implement this advice?

Comment: This is an interesting article which confirms Youssef's answer: http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/