# HttpClient and setting Authorization headers

Tags: c#, authentication, httpclient

I'm trying to make a simple request to the [Basecamp API](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/#making-a-request), I'm following the instructions provided adding in a sample user agent and my credentials yet I keep getting a `403 Forbidden` response back.

My credentials are definitely correct so is it a case of my request/credentials being set incorrectly?

This is what I have (removed personal info):

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("User-Agent", "MyApp [EMAIL ADDRESS]") });

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "[USERNAME]", "[PASSWORD]"))));

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://basecamp.com/[USER ID]/api/v1/projects.json", content);
var responseContent = response.Content;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
     Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A quick look over their documentation seems to indicate that the [projects.json](https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/projects.md) endpoint accepts the following in the body of the POST:

```
{
    "name": "This is my new project!",
    "description": "It's going to run real smooth"
}
```

You're sending the `User-Agent` as the POST body. I'd suggest you change your code as follows:

```
    var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "[USERNAME]", "[PASSWORD]")));
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "MyApp [EMAIL ADDRESS]");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
            "https://basecamp.com/[USER ID]/api/v1/projects.json",
            new {
                name = "My Project",
                description = "My Project Description"
            });

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
    }
```

This posts the payload as specified in the docs and sets your user agent in the headers as it should be.

Comment: Was coding without IDE, should probably have said that :)

Comment: Please also consider why wrapping the client into a short lived `using` _might_ be bad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client