# How to send a Post body in the HttpClient request in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpclient

I have written the code below to send headers, post parameters. The problem is that I am using SendAsync since my request can be GET or POST. How can I add POST Body to this peice of code so that if there is any post body data it gets added in the request that I make and if its simple GET or POST without body it send the request that way. Please update the code below:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// Add a new Request Message
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(RequestHTTPMethod, ToString());

// Add our custom headers
if (RequestHeader != null)
{
    foreach (var item in RequestHeader)
    {

        requestMessage.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

    }
}

// Add request body


// Send the request to the server
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

// Get the response
responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Please see updated answer, it has a nicer approach.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

#### UPDATE 2:

From [@Craig Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3034366/craig-brown):

> As of .NET 5 you can do:
> `requestMessage.Content = JsonContent.Create(new { Name = "John Doe", Age = 33 });`

See [JsonContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent?view=net-5.0) class documentation

#### UPDATE 1:

Oh, it can be even nicer (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679340/2571926)):

```
requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"age\":33}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

This depends on what content do you have. You need to initialize your `requestMessage.Content` property with new [HttpContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.118).aspx). For example:

```
...
// Add request body
if (isPostRequest)
{
    requestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content);
}
...
```

where `content` is your encoded content. You also should include correct Content-type header.

Comment: How to write a Json using a jsonSerializer into the content?

Comment: @GiriB I use the Newtonsoft.Json package to do it like so:

`requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

You could also use you JsonSerializer to serialize into a string as you might currently be doing, and then pass that string as the first parameter to the StringContent constructor.

Comment: As of .NET 5 you can do: 
`requestMessage.Content = JsonContent.Create(new {Name = "John Doe", Age = 33});`

Answer (score 17):

I implemented it in the following way. I wanted a generic `MakeRequest` method that could call my API and receive content for the body of the request - and also deserialise the response into the desired type. I create a `Dictionary<string, string>` object to house the content to be submitted, and then set the `HttpRequestMessage` `Content` property with it:

**Generic method to call the API:**

```
    private static T MakeRequest<T>(string httpMethod, string route, Dictionary<string, string> postParams = null)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(httpMethod), $"{_apiBaseUri}/{route}");

            if (postParams != null)
                requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postParams);   // This is where your content gets added to the request body


            HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result;

            string apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            try
            {
                // Attempt to deserialise the reponse to the desired type, otherwise throw an expetion with the response from the api.
                if (apiResponse != "")
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(apiResponse);
                else
                    throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"An error ocurred while calling the API. It responded with the following message: {response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Call the method:**

```
    public static CardInformation ValidateCard(string cardNumber, string country = "CAN")
    { 
        // Here you create your parameters to be added to the request content
        var postParams = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "cardNumber", cardNumber }, { "country", country } };
        // make a POST request to the "cards" endpoint and pass in the parameters
        return MakeRequest<CardInformation>("POST", "cards", postParams);
    }
```

Comment: Couple of problems with this implementation.  First, it is not async.  The use of ".Result" causes this to be a blocking call.  Second problem is it doesn't scale! See my answer on why here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client/35045301#35045301  Third problem is you are throwing exceptions to handle control-flow. This is not a good practice. See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/da0007-avoid-using-exceptions-for-control-flow?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll check those links

Comment: @AdamHey its good for synchronous requests, thanks!

Comment: Also, you've got a memory leak. `HttpRequestMessage` implements `IDisposable` so you need to wrap it in a `using`

Answer (score 0):

I did create a method:

```
public static StringContent GetBodyJson(params (string key, string value)[] param)
    {
        if (param.Length == 0)
            return null;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.Append(" { ");

        foreach((string key, string value) in param)
        {
            builder.Append(" \"" + key + "\" :"); // key
            builder.Append(" \"" + value + "\" ,"); // value
        }

        builder.Append(" } ");

        return new StringContent(builder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    }
```

obs : Use StringContent in HttpContent, the inheritance is StringContent -> ByteArrayContent -> HttpContent.