# C# URi string is too long, how to convert to JSON raw

Tags: c#, json, api, post, query-string

Finaly figure out how to send QueryString as POST via HttpClient but another problem, URi string is too long becosue one of the string is file encoded to `ToBase64String`

Is posible to convert this solution:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

queryString.Add("mail_from", FromEmailAddress);
queryString.Add("mail_to", ToEmailAddress);
queryString.Add("mail_Attachment", ZipInBytes);

var response = await client.PostAsync($"/api?{queryString}", null);
```

Is there any other way how to send very long string? In postman working JSON raw data send to API

```
{
     "mail_from":"value",
     "mail_to":"value2,
     "mail_Attachment":"very long string"
}
```

or I'm completely out and its not possible. My goal is send data with file from Outlook to API and save to database.

Comment: I am not familliar with postman do you have the Raw http request send from postman? I suspect "raw data" option to be in the body.

Comment: You can change the maximum query length on the web server but i highly recommend not to unless you don't care about DDOS attacks. I would recommend to use an alternate method that `POST` specially for large data transfer. There are many other ways to achieve this other than using `POST`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158452/how-to-send-a-post-body-in-the-httpclient-request-in-windows-phone-8

Comment: @xdtTransform ````request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n    \"mail_from\":\"mail@mail.com\",\r\n    \"mail_to\":\"mailfrom@mail.com\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);```` can be placed in this code ````variable```` insteed ````mail@mail.com```` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should (if possible) send data such as files in the body, not the QueryString.

For instance:

```cs
//Class containing all POST data
public class PostBody{
   public string FromEmailAddress{get;set;}
   public string ToEmailAddress{get;set;}
   public string ZipInBytes{get;set;}
}

// Populate model
PostBody body = new PostBody{ FromEmailAddress = FromEmailAddress, ToEmailAddress = ToEmailAddress, ZipInBytes = ZipInBytes};

// Serialize to JSON
var serializedBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

// Set content type
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

// Do request with serialized JSON as post body
var response = await client.PostAsync($"/api?{queryString}", serializedBody);
```