# Refactor HttpWebRequest to HttpClient?

Tags: c#

How would I convert this to HttpClient? What I'm looking to do is submit a Tweet to the Twitter api and get the response as Json.  The HttpWebRequest is working fine but I just want to port it to HttpClient.  I made an attempt at it in the second code example, but it's not actually sending or receiving the response.

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
WebResponse response = null;
string responseCode = String.Empty;
try
{
    string postBody = "status=" + EncodingUtils.UrlEncode(status);

    request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(resource_url);        
    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {                       
            writer.Write(postBody);
        }
    }
    using (response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        responseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode.ToString();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure)
    {
        request.Abort();
        request = null;
    }
    throw ex;
}
return responseCode;
```

This is what I've tried to get it work:

```
private async Task<string> MakeWebRequest1(string status, string resource_url, string authHeader)
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        clientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;
        clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        string responseCode = "";
        string postBody = "status=" + EncodingUtils.UrlEncode(status);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(resource_url),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,

        };
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
       // request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.Content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");//CONTENT-TYPE header

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            //  Stream stuff = await client.GetStreamAsync(resource_url);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    responseCode = "OK";
                }
            }
        }
        clientHandler.Dispose();
        return responseCode;
    }
enter code here
```

---

I've tried to add another parameter to the request and it's always coming back as 401 unauthorized.  I'm trying to create a Twitter thread.  If I remove the in_reply_to_status_id then it's fine.

```
data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
      ["status"] = "@username + status,
      ["in_reply_to_status_id"] = "1167588690929115136"
};
```

The Twitter API describes it here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793761/httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest-for-better-performance-and-security-and-less-connec

Comment: The default headers in the HttpClient may be different from the HttpWebRrequest.  You may need to capture the current working code with a sniffer and then add any missing headers to the new HttpClient.

Comment: There still is not a problem statement in this post. What is the problem?

Comment: I added more detail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) to understand why a static client is being used.

```
static Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => {
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
        PreAuthenticate = true,
        AllowAutoRedirect = true
    };
    return new HttpClient(clientHandler);
});

private async Task<string> PostStatusRequestAsync(string status, string resource_url, string authHeader) {
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, resource_url)) {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            ["status"] = status
        };

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.Value.SendAsync(request)) {
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of the [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/FormUrlEncodedContent.cs/) for the request body, which will encode and concatenate the data as well as take care of the mime type header

> ...but it's not actually sending or receiving the response.

Ensure that the above is not invoked as a synchronous blocking call, like `.Result`, which could cause a deadlock.

For example, an async event handler can be used to make the async call

```
public async void onButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    //Non-blocking call
    var tweetRequestCode = await PostStatusRequestAsync(TweetText, AuthUtils.GetResourceUrl(), AuthUtils.GetWebRequestHeader())); 

    //back on UI thread
    //...
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that works.  Is the proper way to call this, var t = Task.Run(() => MakeWebRequest1(TweetText, AuthUtils.GetResourceUrl(), AuthUtils.GetWebRequestHeader()));
                t.Wait();
                tweetRequestCode = t.Result;

Comment: @CharlesOwen No the `.Result` and `.Wait()` are blocking calls that can cause deadlocks. Because of the async nature of HttpClient, it should be awaited.

Comment: @CharlesOwen is that how you currently call it?

Comment: Because it blocks the UI. Use an async event handler instead.

Comment: @CharlesOwen provide more details/context about how and where the call is being made. Lets see if we can find a proper solution to making a safe non blocking call.

Comment: public async Task<string> SubmitTweet(string TweetText)
 {
           string tweetRequestCode = String.Empty;
           try
           {                
                AuthUtils.SetupAuthentication(TweetText);
                LogUtils.LogTransmissionStart(new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name);

               tweetRequestCode = await MakeWebRequest1(TweetText, AuthUtils.GetResourceUrl(), AuthUtils.GetWebRequestHeader());
                                
            }

Comment: @CharlesOwen I provided a simplified example in the answer. You should be able to follow a similar pattern with the code you just provided.

Comment: Yes my method now uses that syntax.  Thanks!