# HttpWebRequest BeginRead issue on .net core 3.1 / .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am moving my class library helper for `HttpWebRequest` (standard .net class) from **.NET 4.6.2** to **.NET core 3.1**.

And I discovered the following issue with **.NET core 3.1**:
When I call `responseStream.BeginRead` it calls via the Stack!
So it is the reason of issue: when stack ends application fails due to stack overflow error.

**.NET 4.6.2** behavior is different - it calls `BeginRead` on Thread Pool.
And it works right for years without any issue.

I cannot find the reason why **.NET core 3.1**
has different behavior for `BeginRead`.

If you know how to fix `HttpWebRequest` `BeginRead` or any ideas share with me, please.

Comment: You may choose to use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` in **.NET core** project. Related topics [When to use WebClient vs. HttpClient vs. HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793761/httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest-for-better-performance-security-and-less-connectio) and [HttpClient vs HttpWebRequest for better performance, security and less connections](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3198673/when-to-use-webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest.html)

Comment: Yes, I can, thanks! But my codebase is too big to change HttpWebRequest to HttpClient, started at 2009 

Comment: That's huge project. Perhaps building a wrapper on top of HttpClient to mitigate HttpWebRequest.

Comment: yes, I think about that also, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is standart behaviour for .net core and your code has to be ready for that.

You have to analyse in your code
**ReadIAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously == true/false**
and decide what to do this that
if CompletedSynchronously == true your have to return from the function.

**Check docs**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncresult.completedsynchronously?view=net-7.0

**Notes to Implementers**
Most implementers of the IAsyncResult interface will not use this property and should return false. Beginning with the .NET Framework 4.5, a task that is created with the FromAsync(IAsyncResult, Action, TaskCreationOptions) method will not complete if this property is not implemented correctly. See Application Compatibility in 4.5.

**Notes to Callers**
Use this property to determine if the asynchronous operation completed synchronously. For example, this property can return true for an asynchronous I/O operation if the I/O request was small.

**Find more details here**
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/issues/177