# Static HttpClient thread safe on ASP.net HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety, httprequest, static-libraries, dotnet-httpclient

We are creating a wrapper for HttpClient. As we are going to follow performance optimization guidance from https://github.com/mspnp/performance-optimization. We want to avoid anti-pattern - Improper instantiation mentioned in that document. I referred this guidance to my team to use static HttpClient. The feedback I have got is on thread-safety. Each request has a header containing user claim. Since I have a static HttpClient, will it be thread-safe? If we have multiple requests hitting the code (for example GET) at the same time, will it be a race condition to set header? We have implementation as below.

```
public class HttpClientHelper{
private static readonly HttpClient _HttpClient;
static HttpClientHelper() {
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SOME_CONFIG_VALUE);
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallHttpClientPostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent requestBody)
{
    AddHttpRequestHeader(httpClient);
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, requestBody); //Potential thread synchronization issue???
    return response;
}

public HttpResponseMessage CallHttpClientGet(string requestUri)
{
    AddHttpRequestHeader(httpClient);
    var response = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result; //Potential thread synchronization issue???
    return response;
}

private void AddHttpRequestHeader(HttpClient client)
{
    string HeaderName = "CorrelationId";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(Properties.Settings.Default.HttpClientAuthHeaderScheme, GetTokenFromClaims()); //Race condition???
    if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains(HeaderName))
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove(HeaderName);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderName, Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId.ToString());
}
```

}

Comment: Any reason that `CallHttpClientGet` is not async? By calling `.Result` you are blocking the thread and inviting potential deadlocks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your team is correct, this is far from thread safe. Consider this scenario:

- Thread A sets CorrelationId header to "foo".
- Thread B sets CorrelationId header to "bar".
- Thread A sends request, which contains thread B's CorrelationId.

A better approach would be for your CallXXX methods to create new [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage) objects, and set the header on those, and use [HttpClient.SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176) to make the call.

Keep in mind also that re-using `HttpClient` instances is only beneficial if you're making multiple calls to the same host.

Comment: "Keep in mind also that re-using HttpClient instances is only beneficial if you're making multiple calls to the same host" - do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @OhadSchneider It's based on [Daryl Miller's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561368/62600) to use one instance "for each distinct API that you connect to". Reason being that performance benefits (not having to open a new connection, etc) are only relevant per host, as are certain HttpClient properties like DefatultHeaders. However, the now-famous [socket problem](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) could change my advice a little. Can Windows reclaim a socket in TIME_WAIT for use with a different host? I'm not sure. I posted the question on that article.