# Windows Phone HttpClient GetAsync performance

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working with twitch REST API for education purposes(MVVM pattern) on Windows Phone platform. I noticed pure performance while using HttpClient:

1. I get a collection of 10 elements
2. Pass it to CheckCannelStreamStatus

I removed the code because it was draft for prototype.

Like in the answer bellow the problem is in the `HttpClient.GetAsync` that resulted in ~671ms execution time.

Comment: Why don't you reuse the same `HttpClient` for both methods?

Comment: Why should I? It's separate method that can be called from any place.

Comment: I think the '7686ms execution time' most cause by network transfer and server execution

Comment: Because it can be more efficient. Pull it out as a parameter instead, then. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22561368/682105, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15708633/682105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the "performance" of `HttpClient`. The reason for this is  rather that you're going 10 times to a server to get back some information. That'll be ~768ms per request, which sounds reasonable given some latency. There's little the `HttpClient` can do about latency and server response times.

To verify this is the case, I suggest you pop up Fiddler or a similar tool to make sure the response time is the offender. You could also wrap both `client.GetAsync` and `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TwitchStream>()` in separate stopwatches and verify that the serialization is not the root cause here.

To decrease the time it takes to get all the needed information, I'd suggest you look into executing the HTTP requests in parallel. `HttpClient` is designed to be both reused both for multiple calls, and across multiple threads. So reusing a single instance and executing multiple requests in parallel, using something like `Task.WhenAll` or similar, will make it perform better.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right. I will look for links you provided. Thank you.