# How make an HTTP request in C#

Tags: c#, curl

How do i make a curl request in c# in windows or

i want to make web request with this parameters and it should receive a valid response

request

```
curl 'http://www1.bloomingdales.com/api/store/v2/stores/367,363,6113,364,4946?upcNumber=808593890516' -H 'Cookie:shippingCountry=US;' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' --compressed
```

In perl i would simply do

```
my $page = `curl --silent 'http://www1.bloomingdales.com/api/store/v2/stores/367,363,6113,364,4946?upcNumber=808593890516' -H 'Cookie:shippingCountry=US;' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' --compressed 2>/dev/null`;
```

Then

```
my $page
```

The results are store in above variable.

How to do similarly in c#???

Comment: Are you trying to invoke CURL, or do you simply want to issue a web request?

Comment: i want to make web request with those parameters and it should receive a valid response

Comment: @Mounarajan, I think you should reframe the question. Your comment above is a better description of what you want to do.

Comment: Done @SilentMonk do you know answer?

Comment: @Thomas none of the answers there shows how to set all the required headers and cookies.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [The OP should be pragmatic about the question.  If those things are needed, they should be listed out in exactness and not something answers should assume](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 9):

I would highly recommend using the new [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Please read the notes at the bottom of this answer**

Excerpt from MSDN.

```
static async void Main()
{

    // Create a New HttpClient object.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
    try 
    {
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
       // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

       Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }  
    catch(HttpRequestException e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");    
       Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
    }

    // Need to call dispose on the HttpClient object
    // when done using it, so the app doesn't leak resources
    client.Dispose(true);
 }
```

Since this answer was originally written there are some caveats about using HttpClient.  (TLDR; it should be a singleton)

[Using HttpClient As It Was Intended (Because You’re Not)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194406/Using-HttpClient-As-It-Was-Intended-Because-You-re)

[What is the overhead of creating a new HttpClient per call in a WebAPI client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client)

[YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)
E.g.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
// access req.Headers to get/set header values before calling GetResponse. 
// req.CookieContainer allows you access cookies.

var response = req.GetResponse();
string webcontent;
using (var strm = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    webcontent = strm.ReadToEnd();
}
```

You can set headers/cookies on request by accessing [Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) properties of request object. You can also access various properties of response object to get various values.

Comment: Certainly works, but it's not the recommended class in the current version of .Net (4.5).