# Re-set the certificate of singleton httpclient (Reconfiguring IHttpclientFactory?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

Using C#, .NET Core 3.1

I add a singleton `httpclient` via in `startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IClientLogic, ClientLogicA>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
   var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
   
   var cert= GetCertFromX();

   handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

   return handler;
});
```

But lets say, later in `ClientLogicA` class, I want to change the certificate, how do I go about doing this and will the change persist for future uses of the httpclient singleton?

Comment: The singleton pattern creates just a single instance of a class to the project. Since all code depending using this singleton use the same instance, when changing some data of the instance that change will persist.

Comment: hi @SimonTulling Thanks for the response. I went away and tested this but found it not the case. With the injected instance, I set a new instance of the client for it and accessed it in a subsequent call only to find that it does not have the certificate as though it was never set.

Comment: You set a breakpoint on the `handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);` and `cert` is valid every time this lambda executes?

Comment: @Andy Yep. The issue is not adding the certificate on startup but changing the certificate to a different one later.  For example, how do I change certificate say for example for each client request whilst retaining a singleton HttpClient?

Comment: You said in a previous comment: *I set a new instance of the client for it and accessed it in a subsequent call only to find that it does not have the certificate* -- how exactly did you "set a new instance"?

Comment: I think I have a  solution. Would you be open to changing it from `Typed HttpClient` objects to `Named HttpClient` objects? I am not a huge fan of `Typed` clients.

Comment: @Andy I am open to that but what are you suggesting? :)
Also, I just found this and I don't think there is a way: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/521

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what you want to do is modify the certificate of a `HttpClient` that is being produced by an `IHttpClientFactory`. It looks as though Microsoft may be adding this type of functionality in .NET 5, but in the meantime, we need to come up with a way to do it now.

This solution will work with both Named `HttpClient` and Typed `HttpClient` objects.

So the issue here is to create the Named or Typed `HttpClient` where the certificate collection that is bound to the `HttpClient` can be updated at any time. The problem is we can only set the creation parameters for `HttpClient` once. After that, the `IHttpClientFactory` reuses those settings over and over.

So, let's start by looking at how we inject our services:

> Named HttpClient Injection Routine

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>(); 

services.AddSingleton<ICertificateService, CertificateService>();

services.AddHttpClient("MyCertBasedClient").
    ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
    new CertBasedHttpClientHandler(
        sp.GetRequiredService<ICertificateService>()));
```

> Typed HttpClient Injection Routine

```
services.AddSingleton<ICertificateService, CertificateService>();

services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>().
    ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
        new CertBasedHttpClientHandler(
            sp.GetRequiredService<ICertificateService>()));
```

We inject a `ICertificateService` as *singleton* that holds our current certificate and allows other services to change it. `IMyService` is injected manually when using Named `HttpClient`, while when using a Typed `HttpClient`, `IMyService` will be automatically injected. When it comes time for the `IHttpClientFactory` to create our `HttpClient`, it will call the lambda and produce an extended `HttpClientHandler` which takes our `ICertificateService` from our service pipeline as a constructor parameter.

This next part is the source to the `ICertificateService`. This service maintains the certificate with an "id" (which is just a timestamp of when it was last updated).

> CertificateService.cs

```
public interface ICertificateService
{
    void UpdateCurrentCertificate(X509Certificate cert);
    X509Certificate GetCurrentCertificate(out long certId);
    bool HasCertificateChanged(long certId);
}

public sealed class CertificateService : ICertificateService
{
    private readonly object _certLock = new object();
    private X509Certificate _currentCert;
    private long _certId;
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public CertificateService()
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public bool HasCertificateChanged(long certId)
    {
        lock(_certLock)
        {
            return certId != _certId;
        }
    }

    public X509Certificate GetCurrentCertificate(out long certId)
    {
        lock(_certLock)
        {
            certId = _certId;
            return _currentCert;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateCurrentCertificate(X509Certificate cert)
    {
        lock(_certLock)
        {
            _currentCert = cert;
            _certId = _stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        }
    }
}
```

This final part is the class that implements a custom `HttpClientHandler`. With this we can hook in to *all* HTTP requests being made by the client. If the certificate has changed, we swap it out before the request is made.

> CertBasedHttpClientHandler.cs

```
public sealed class CertBasedHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private readonly ICertificateService _certService;
    private long _currentCertId;

    public CertBasedHttpClientHandler(ICertificateService certificateService)
    {
        _certService = certificateService;
        var cert = _certService.GetCurrentCertificate(out _currentCertId);
        if(cert != null)
        {
            ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        }
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(_certService.HasCertificateChanged(_currentCertId))
        {
            ClientCertificates.Clear();
            var cert = _certService.GetCurrentCertificate(out _currentCertId);
            if(cert != null)
            {
                ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            }
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Now I think the biggest down-side to this is if the `HttpClient` is in the middle of a request on another thread, we could run in to a race condition. You could alleviate that by guarding the code in the `SendAsync` with a `SemaphoreSlim` or any other asynchronous thread synchronizing pattern, but that could cause a bottle-neck so I didn't bother doing that. If you want to see that added, I will update this answer.

Comment: Fully tested - works! Thank you so much!!  I am just wondering if there is much difference in performance between _httpClientFactory.CreateClient() per request versus an injected HttpClient (both using DI service.AddHttpClient() on startup).

Comment: @PKCS12 -- I will update this answer and add some code on how to make it to use `Typed` HttpClient objects. I am not 100% sure on how `Named` HttpClient's work as opposed to `Typed`, but the end result will be the same.