# Setting up HttpClient in .NET to make it work with multiple threads and to provide concurrency

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

After reading the posts below about recommended usage of `HttpClient`, I changed my code from instantiating `HttpClient` per request within a using block to a long-lived object.

[Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed)

[What is the overhead of creating a new HttpClient per call in a WebAPI client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client)

My implementation is part of a low-level api, and would be to make requests from from different parts of the app running on different threads, so thread-safety and concurrency when making requests needs to be guaranteed as well.

I even went on to make it a singleton as below, so there is just one instance of HttpClient used throughout the app. (fourth version form John SKeet's article)

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

```
public sealed class MyHttpClient
{       
    private static readonly volatile HttpClient _myHttpClient = new HttpClient();

    static MyHttpClient() {}
    private MyHttpClient(){ }

    public static HttpClient MyHttpClientObj
    {
        get
        {               
            return _myHttpClient;
        }
    }
}
```

And below is an example of how this gets used

```
  public IEnumerable<string> GetSomeData(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent bodyParameters)
  {
      try
      {
          //is it possible to configure timeout here instead, such that every request will have its one timeout duration?
          var response = MyHttpClient.MyHttpClientObj.PostAsync(url, bodyParameters);

          var result = response.Result;

          if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
             //log and return null
          }

          var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

          return data;

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          //logging exceptions
      }
  }
```

When making requests via `HttpClient`, I've made sure to use only the therad-safe methods listed below, but when deserializing the response, `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is used. This is because the higher level calls don't support async responses yet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5

However, I still have a few questions.

1. Is this approach Thread-safe and stable enough to not cause any memory leaks?
2. How can I configure the Timeout for every request?
3. Is it necessary to specify 'Connection: keep-alive' in DefaultHeaders?
4. How can I add a custom header/modify a default header for every request?
5. And finally, Are there any known performance issues/drawbacks in using HttpClient this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this approach is thread-safe, as you call a thread-safe methods and do not you any synchronization logic, so your client threads simply independent from each other.
2. You can use an overload with CancellationTokenSource, with calling it method `CancelAfter`, this approach is recommended by MSDN.
3. No, but if your connection do require some interaction between client and server, it is highly recommended approach for HTTP/1.1, it reduces the overhead to recreating the socket connection and some handshakes between participating sides.
4. You can use the [`Headers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers.aspx) property of the `FormUrlEncodedContent` class, simply add a header you need to it.
5. The huge drawback for your solution is `.Result` call, as it blocks the current thread. You can try to refactor your approach with `TaskCompletionSource` usage so you could possibly use `async` methods internally. This will provide you a possibility for the threads to do something else rather than wait for result.

Answer (score 3):

It's thread safe, and recommended.

Depending on your usage, the biggest thing may be to raise the connection limit to your desired level of concurrency:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 16;
```

Without this set, concurrent requests to a single host will sit in a queue until they can be issued. And they'll time out if they're not got to in time.

I'd also recommend using pipelining to improve performance:

```
new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler() { AllowPipelining = true });
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest performance issue you will encounter using HttpClient in a highly concurrent environment is the number of concurrent connections to any given url is limited to 2 by default.  You can increase this for all endpoints using [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) or get a specific ServicePoint using [ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5f0atwd(v=vs.110).aspx) and set [ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit.aspx)