# HttpClient await SendAsync deadlock

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, async-await

I have been battling this for days now and can't figure it out or why it is the way it is. I am hoping one of you masterminds can explain it to me.

This is the code in question:

```
public async static Task<RemoteFileDetails> GetRemoteFileDetailsAsync(string strUrl, double dblTimeoutSeconds = 15.0)
{
    try
    {
        using (var hc = new HttpClient())
        {
            hc.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dblTimeoutSeconds);
            using (var h = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, strUrl))
            {
                h.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UserAgent);
                using (var rm = await hc.SendAsync(h))
                {
                    rm.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return new RemoteFileDetails()
                    {
                        Url = strUrl,
                        FileName = rm.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName,
                        FileSize = rm.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        LastModified = rm.Content.Headers.LastModified.GetValueOrDefault().LocalDateTime,
                        Valid = true
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return new RemoteFileDetails();
}
```

All this does is puts in a HEAD request on a URL and grabs the certain header results.

The issue here is about 50% of the time it deadlocks (pauses for 60 seconds or so, then throws a `TaskCanceledException`), the other 50% it works wonderfully. Now, I added network logging, and this is what's happening on deadlock:

```
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2928] HttpWebRequest#3567399::HttpWebRequest(https://www.example.com/file.txt#-114720138)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [2928] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
    System.Net Information: 0 : [2928] RAS supported: True
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2928] Exiting HttpWebRequest#3567399::HttpWebRequest() 
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2928] HttpWebRequest#3567399::HttpWebRequest(uri: 'https://www.example.com/file.txt', connectionGroupName: '565144')
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2928] Exiting HttpWebRequest#3567399::HttpWebRequest() 
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5456] HttpWebRequest#3567399::BeginGetResponse()
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2244] HttpWebRequest#3567399::Abort()
    System.Net Error: 0 : [2244] Exception in HttpWebRequest#3567399:: - The request was aborted: The request was canceled..
/////// THIS IS WHERE THE 30-60 SECOND PAUSE HAPPENS ////////
    System.Net Error: 0 : [5456] Can't retrieve proxy settings for Uri 'https://www.example.com/file.txt'. Error code: 12180.
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5456] ServicePoint#39086322::ServicePoint(www.example.com:443)
    System.Net Information: 0 : [5456] Associating HttpWebRequest#3567399 with ServicePoint#39086322
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2244] Exiting HttpWebRequest#3567399::Abort() 
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5456] HttpWebRequest#3567399::EndGetResponse()
    System.Net Error: 0 : [5456] Exception in HttpWebRequest#3567399::EndGetResponse - The request was aborted: The request was canceled..
    System.Net Verbose: 0 : [5456] Exiting HttpWebRequest#3567399::BeginGetResponse()   -> ContextAwareResult#36181605
```

So, it looks like the HttpClient() object is getting disposed? But how? To verify that this may be the case, I changed the code to this:

```
private static HttpClient _hc;
public async static Task<RemoteFileDetails> GetRemoteFileDetailsAsync(string strUrl, double dblTimeoutSeconds = 15.0)
{
    _hc = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        _hc.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dblTimeoutSeconds);
        using (var h = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, strUrl))
        {
            h.Headers.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UserAgent);
            using (var rm = await _hc.SendAsync(h))
            {
                rm.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return new RemoteFileDetails()
                {
                    Url = strUrl,
                    FileName = rm.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName,
                    FileSize = rm.Content.Headers.ContentLength.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    LastModified = rm.Content.Headers.LastModified.GetValueOrDefault().LocalDateTime,
                    Valid = true
                };
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return new RemoteFileDetails();
}
```

but it still deadlocks the same.

Is there any explanation is to why this is happening? I thought async/await was basically "pausing" the routine, so the HttpClient should never dispose, anyway.

Or am I missing the boat totally here and it's something else.

Here is a screencap of the exception:
[image]

**ETA:**
I suppose it's important to show how I am calling this. This is a WPF app using MVVM Light. In the main view model, i am calling this as so:

```
    public MainViewModel(IDataService ds)
    {
        _dataService = ds;
        this.Initialize();
    }

    private async void Initialize()
    {
        var det = await RemoteFileUtils.GetRemoteFileDetailsAsync("https://example.com/file.txt");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false)`? I wonder if you call this function directly from the UI thread.

Comment: @xxbbcc yes, it doesn't change anything. Tried that yesterday. I will update the question to show how I am calling it.

Comment: @xxbbcc OK, i updated the question to show how i'm calling it.

Comment: @Sonic: Since call this.Initialize(); is not awaited it may cause deadlock. Probably this article may be helpful. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: I don't think it's being disposed; the request is being cancelled. [`12180` is `ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED`: "unable to discover the URL of the Proxy Auto-Configuration (PAC) file"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383770(v=vs.85).aspx), so it sounds like a proxy configuration error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem originates with how it is being called.

Do not call that in the constructor of the calling class. Also avoid `async void` unless it is in an event handler.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public MainViewModel(IDataService ds) {
        _dataService = ds;
        this.Initialize += OnInitialize;
        //Un-comment if you want to call event immediately
        //Initialize(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler Initialize;

    private async void OnInitialize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var det = await RemoteFileUtils.GetRemoteFileDetailsAsync("https://example.com/file.txt");
    }

    //Or call this after class has created.
    public void Ready() {
        Initialize(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Next try to not create and dispoase a new `HttpClient` every time you need to make a request. Create one instance and use that through out the life of the application.

> [**keep an instance of HttpClient for the lifetime of your application** for each distinct API that you connect to.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561368/5233410)

`GetRemoteFileDetailsAsync` should also be refactored to be an injectable service rather than being statically accessed.

Comment: One question: You say that I should have only one HttpClient per application. Can I use the HttpClient object between multiple threads at the same time? or would have i have to lock the HttpClient exclusively to the thread until the HTTP transfer is finished?

Comment: @Sonic check the link in the answer. No need to lock the client. it is thread safe

Comment: One more question. In the example above, you say `//Un-comment if you want to call event immediately`, but if I do that, aren't i back in the same boat where I am calling an `async void` method without using await?

Comment: @Sonic Calling event handler this time where async void is allowed. When you get some time read up on this article [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) by Stephen Cleary

Comment: @Sonic just realized my mistake. You are suppose to raise the event, which in turn will call the event handler.