# WCF service call async function

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await, httprequest

I have an async function which is used to send request message to a server. The function is like following:

```
class http
{
    public async Task<string> HttpRequest()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = GetHttpRequestMessage();
        var str1 = await ExecuteRequest(request);
        return str1;
    }

    private async Task<string> ExecuteRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var responses = await client.SendAsync(request);
                responses.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                result = await responses.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private const string _DataTypeJson = @"application/json";
    private HttpRequestMessage GetHttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = GetHeadersUsedForToken();
        string str = "https://test.com//tokens";
        Uri uri = new Uri(str);

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = uri,
        };

        if (null != headers)
        {
            foreach (string key in headers.Keys)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(key, headers[key]);
            }
        }

        // Hard code Accpt type is Json
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_DataTypeJson));

        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        return request;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetHeadersUsedForToken()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "id", "abc" },
            { "secret", "***" }
        };
    }
}
```

This function works fine in **console** project, but when I try to move this function to WCF service, and try to call `HttpRequest()` function in service,

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetData();
}
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Task<string> GetData()
    {
        http test = new http();
        return test.HttpRequest();
    }       
}
```

Exception was thrown:

```
Message An error occurred while sending the request.
InnerException  {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."}
```

Comment: Prematurely calling `Result` defeats the whole purpose of `async` by the way

Comment: And deadlocks..

Comment: @MickyD, Thanks your reply. The function is just a demo function which hide some details. My core problem is the function does not work in WCF.  Could you help on this?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, thanks for your reply. Any suggestion for my problem?

Comment: How are we to know which code is real or not? Post your _actual code_.   Good luck!

Comment: @MickyD sorry to make confusion. I didn't upload GetHttpRequestMessage and ConvertStreamToString function, because the problem occurs during call ExecuteRequest function.

Comment: async/await is about whole (lengthy) call chains. You still din't post a complete picture. Best is to create a [mcve] from scratch here. Reproduce the problem in <= 50 lines.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, thanks your reply. Update my code.

Comment: Side note: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @PauloMorgado  LOL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With async/await you need to make it async all the way through.

Make the service a Task-based asynchronous service

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1 {
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetData();
}
```

With that, it is a simple matter of making the rest of the code async all the way through.

```
public class http {
    public async Task<string> HttpRequestAsync() {
        var request = GetHttpRequestMessage();
        string str1 = await ExecuteRequest(request);
        Console.WriteLine(str1);
        return str1;
    }

    //...code removed for brevity as they are already Task-based
}
```

This should now allow the function to be used in the service implementation

```
public class Service1 : IService1 {
    public Task<string> GetData() {
        http test = new http(); 
        return test.HttpRequestAsync();
    }
}
```

In the original example provided the code was mixing async and blocking calls `.Result`, which can lead to deadlocks

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

I would also advise making the `HttpClient` static and reuse it rather than creating multiple instances and disposing of them.

Reference [**keep an instance of HttpClient for the lifetime of your application** for each distinct API that you connect to.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22561368/5233410)

UPDATE:

Another possibility is that the URL being called is HTTPS.

Consider applying the following before making the request via the `HttpClient`

```
//Handle TLS protocols
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
    System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: thanks your reply. I modified my code follow your advise, but still failed in WCF service. Same exception was thrown. It will be appreciate if you can give further advise. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kerwen chekc to see if it is a certificate issue as you are making a call to a HTTPS, URL

Comment: Yes, it is! After I add SecurityProtocol, it works! Appreciate your effort, Nkosi!