# Sending requests with different headers using HttpClient

Tags: c#

There is a similar [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client) which talks about the performance of `HttpClient` objects and recommends to use one `HttpClient` instance per application. My project requires me to send multiple webservice requests to the same URI but each with a different set of headers. Should I create a new `HttpClient` instance for every request, knowing the fact that `DefaultRequestHeaders` will be same for all requests if I use a `static` instance.

Comment: Although you shouldn't create a new HttpClient for each instance, it's not a problem to create a few different ones for different purposes.

Answer (score 12):

You can:

- Set default headers on your global instance
- Create multiple global (logical) instances with different default configurations
- Set (additional) headers per request
- Create new HttpClient using IHttpClientFactory

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1

### Global Default Headers

Here you create one client instance and add headers that will be applied to all requests.

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", contentTypeValue);
```

### Multiple Preconfigured Instances

In this dotnet core 2.1 example, we register a preconfigured named instance:

```
services.AddHttpClient("github", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    // Github API versioning
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    // Github requires a user-agent
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
});
```

Later we'll inject `IHttpClientFactory`, and get this pre configured client like so:

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("github");
```

An alternative to named client are "typed clients": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients. Both approaches will keep the basic configuration at one place.

### Headers per Request

If your headers belong to a single request only, simple set them per request.

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Using this approach you can use a shared `HttpClient` instance.

### IHttpClientFactory

If you want a new "clean" HttpClient instance, the recommended approach for asp.net core is to inject `IHttpClientFactory` and use `_clientFactory.CreateClient()`.

```
public class MyService {
  public MyService (IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
  {
    _clientFactory = clientFactory;
  }
  public async Task DoSomething()
  {
    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
    // do request
  }
}
```

Comment: I am implementing my logic as per "_Headers per Request_" approach in your answer. I will let you guys know about the performance implications and accept the answer if it works as expected.