# Reuse or create new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, httpclient

There was a resolved question for **System.Net.Http.HttpClient**. 
[what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client)

The answer is: Reuse HttpClient instance instead of creating new instance.

Now I am using **Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient** in an UWP application.

Regarding **Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient** ,the answer is the same ?

Comment: The fact that it's UWP does not change the way the library works, so yes, it's the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reuse or create new `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`

The short answer yes, it could be reused. We often make single-instance pattern to package `HttpClient`. You could keep an instance of `HttpClient` for the lifetime of your application for each distinct API. And the following is thread safe.

```
public class HttClientProvider
{
    private static HttpClient _instance = null;
    private static readonly object _instanceLock = new object(); 
    public static HttpClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == _instance)
            {
                lock (_instanceLock)
                {
                    if (null == _instance)
                    {
                        _instance = new HttpClient();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```