# HttpClient - Best Practices Workaround

Tags: c#, httpclient

I do understand that [HttpClient has been designed to be re-used for multiple calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560971/what-is-the-overhead-of-creating-a-new-httpclient-per-call-in-a-webapi-client) and I have done extensive research on why it is ideal to create a single static instance or use Singleton for the HttpClient since after disposing there is a chance that the TCP sockets remains open due to the TCP connection lifecycle.

The below is a singleton class I created for my central library in order to keep and reuse a single instance of `HttpClient`. Can someone help me to convert it to use `IHttpClientFactory` instead?

```
public class HttpFunctions
{
    #region Class Members
    private HttpClientHandler Http_Client_Handler { get; set; }
    private HttpClient Http_Client { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Constructor
    public HttpFunctions()
    {
        InitHttpClient();
    }

    ~HttpFunctions()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    #endregion


    #region Methods
    #region Post
    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        T1 response = new T1();

        try
        {
            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            if (authenticationToken != null)
                Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationToken;

            if (httpHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach (Tuple<string, string> httpHeader in httpHeaders)
                    Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(httpHeader.Item1, httpHeader.Item2);
            }

            if (cookies != null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
                    Http_Client_Handler.CookieContainer.Add(requestUri, cookie);
            }

            string jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
            using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                string failedReason = string.Empty;
                bool succeeded = ProcessFunctions.InnerFunctions.PerformUsingRetriesIf_ReturnIsFalse(() =>
                {
                    bool success = false;

                    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = Http_Client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent).Result)
                    {
                        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            response = parseResponseMethod(httpResponse);
                            success = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            failedReason = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
                            success = false;
                        }
                    }

                    return success;
                }, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);

                if (!succeeded)
                    throw new Exception(failedReason);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cookies != null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
                    Http_Client_Handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(requestUri)
                                                        .Cast<Cookie>()
                                                        .ToList()
                                                        .ForEach(c => c.Expired = true);
            }
            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        }

        return response;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Get
    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        T1 response = new T1();
        try
        {
            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            if (authenticationToken != null)
                Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationToken;

            if (httpHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach (Tuple<string, string> httpHeader in httpHeaders)
                    Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(httpHeader.Item1, httpHeader.Item2);
            }

            string failedReason = string.Empty;
            bool succeeded = ProcessFunctions.InnerFunctions.PerformUsingRetriesIf_ReturnIsFalse(() =>
            {
                bool success = false;

                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = Http_Client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result)
                {
                    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        response = parseResponseMethod(httpResponse);
                        success = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        failedReason = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
                        success = false;
                    }
                }

                return success;
            }, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);

            if (!succeeded)
                throw new Exception(failedReason);
        }
        finally { Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear(); }

        return response;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Parse
    public T1 ParseToResponseContract<T1>(HttpResponseMessage httpResponse) where T1 : new()
    {
        T1 results = new T1();

        try
        {
            if (httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString().ToLower().Contains("application/json"))
            {
                string jsonResponse = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                using (MemoryStream jsonStreamResponse = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonResponse)))
                {
                    //DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings()
                    //{
                    //    //DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
                    //    UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true,
                    //    EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never
                    //};

                    DataContractJsonSerializer dcs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T1));
                    results = (T1)dcs.ReadObject(jsonStreamResponse);
                }
            }
        }
        finally { }

        return results;
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion


    #region Private Methods
    private void InitHttpClient()
    {
        if (Http_Client == null)
        {
            Http_Client_Handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() };

            Http_Client = new HttpClient(Http_Client_Handler);

            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void Dispose()
    {
        if (Http_Client != null)
        {
            Http_Client.Dispose();

            Http_Client = null;
        }

        if (Http_Client_Handler != null)
        {
            Http_Client_Handler.Dispose();

            Http_Client_Handler = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Static Properties
    private static readonly IHttpFunctions mHttpFunctions = new HttpFunctions();

    public static IHttpFunctions InnerFunctions
    {
        get { return mHttpFunctions; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

---

Comment: What kind of application is it?

Comment: [Use IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Comment: @AluanHaddad - It is a central Library project that is called by all my other apps so that I do not need to repeat and retest code that is reused across different project types.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - IHttpClientFactory needs certain configuration pertaining to the app that is using it. Since I wish to centralize this "API Calling" functionality, I do not think it is the ideal in my case.

Comment: Do you use .net core?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad - yes, but for my central library I used .Net Standard in order to make it multi-platform.

Comment: It's not a problem just add ``Microsoft.Extensions.Http`` to library and use ``IHttpClientFactory``.

Comment: Thank you for that @SaeedEsmaeelinejad. So all i do is to add a `private IHttpClientFactory Http_Client_Factory;` as a global class variable, and then in the `InitHttpClient()` method I change the `Http_Client = new HttpClient(Http_Client_Handler);` to be `Http_Client = Http_Client_Factory.CreateClient();` and then leave the rest as is? What about the `HttpClientHandler` for when cookies need to be added to the client instance?

Comment: Yes, I suggest to use ``Named client type`` and then you can create custom ``HttpClientHandler`` one for use cookie and one for without cookie and in your method do ``InitHttpClient(bool useCookie)`` , see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thank you @SaeedEsmaeelinejad. One last question pls, is this a good implementation practice or this defeats the entire concept of `IHttpClientFactory`?


`using (HttpClient client = Http_Client_Factory.CreateClient()) {  }`

Comment: Using is not work for ``HttpClient``.  So don't use it. ``IHttpClientFactory`` creates pool of HttpClients and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

What I think I will end up doing is to use a singleton class in my central Library project and host only one instance of an `HttpClient` (not static) so that for every project making use of this Library will have a separate single instance of this property. I will also implement a Destroyer in order to properly Dispose of the property instance as soon as the calling project terminates.

This however does not solve my problem when having to use an `HttpClientHandler` in order to be able to pass Cookies along side my Post requests. Need some more thought in this aspect.

If you think there is a better way or think that this approach will lead to problems, I would appreciate the heads up.

Thanks again :)

---

The below is the singleton class I created for my central library. Can you help me to convert it to use `IHttpClientFactory` instead? Sorry in advance regarding the overkilling overload methods.

```
public class HttpFunctions
{
    #region Class Members
    private HttpClientHandler Http_Client_Handler { get; set; }
    private HttpClient Http_Client { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Constructor
    public HttpFunctions()
    {
        InitHttpClient();
    }

    ~HttpFunctions()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
    #endregion


    #region Methods
    #region Post
    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(accessToken, payload, requestUri, null, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(accessToken, payload, requestUri, httpHeaders, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(accessToken, payload, requestUri, null, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(ParseToResponseContract<T1>, accessToken, payload, requestUri, httpHeaders, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }


    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, accessToken, payload, requestUri, null, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, accessToken, payload, requestUri, httpHeaders, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, accessToken, payload, requestUri, null, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string accessToken, T2 payload, string requestUri, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authToken = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            authToken = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, requestUri, authToken, httpHeaders, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }
   

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(ParseToResponseContract<T1>, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }


    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        Uri absoluteUri = new Uri(requestUri, UriKind.Absolute);

        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, absoluteUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }



    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }
    
    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(ParseToResponseContract<T1>, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }


    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return PostRequest<T1, T2>(parseResponseMethod, payload, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, cookies, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 PostRequest<T1, T2>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, T2 payload, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, Cookie[] cookies = null, short maxRetries = 5, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        T1 response = new T1();

        try
        {
            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            if (authenticationToken != null)
                Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationToken;

            if (httpHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach (Tuple<string, string> httpHeader in httpHeaders)
                    Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(httpHeader.Item1, httpHeader.Item2);
            }

            if (cookies != null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
                    Http_Client_Handler.CookieContainer.Add(requestUri, cookie);
            }

            string jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
            using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {
                string failedReason = string.Empty;
                bool succeeded = ProcessFunctions.InnerFunctions.PerformUsingRetriesIf_ReturnIsFalse(() =>
                {
                    bool success = false;

                    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = Http_Client.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent).Result)
                    {
                        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            response = parseResponseMethod(httpResponse);
                            success = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            failedReason = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
                            success = false;
                        }
                    }

                    return success;
                }, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);

                if (!succeeded)
                    throw new Exception(failedReason);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cookies != null)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
                    Http_Client_Handler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(requestUri)
                                                        .Cast<Cookie>()
                                                        .ToList()
                                                        .ForEach(c => c.Expired = true);
            }
            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        }

        return response;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Get
    public T1 GetRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1>(string accessToken, string requestUri, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1>(accessToken, requestUri, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1>(string accessToken, string requestUri, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1>(ParseToResponseContract<T1>, accessToken, requestUri, httpHeaders, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string accessToken, string requestUri, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1>(parseResponseMethod, accessToken, requestUri, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequestUsingBearerAuthentication<T1>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string accessToken, string requestUri, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        AuthenticationHeaderValue authToken = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            authToken = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        return GetRequest<T1>(parseResponseMethod, requestUri, authToken, httpHeaders, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }



    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequest<T1>(requestUri, authenticationToken, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequest<T1>(ParseToResponseContract<T1>, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequest<T1>(parseResponseMethod, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, string requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        Uri absoluteUri = new Uri(requestUri, UriKind.Absolute);

        return GetRequest<T1>(parseResponseMethod, absoluteUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }


    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequest<T1>(requestUri, authenticationToken, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }
    
    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequest<T1>(ParseToResponseContract<T1>, requestUri, authenticationToken, httpHeaders, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        return GetRequest<T1>(parseResponseMethod, requestUri, authenticationToken, null, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);
    }

    public T1 GetRequest<T1>(Func<HttpResponseMessage, T1> parseResponseMethod, Uri requestUri, AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationToken = null, Tuple<string, string>[] httpHeaders = null, short maxRetries = 0, bool exponentialRetries = false, double baseValue = 2) where T1 : new()
    {
        T1 response = new T1();
        try
        {
            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            if (authenticationToken != null)
                Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationToken;

            if (httpHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach (Tuple<string, string> httpHeader in httpHeaders)
                    Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(httpHeader.Item1, httpHeader.Item2);
            }

            string failedReason = string.Empty;
            bool succeeded = ProcessFunctions.InnerFunctions.PerformUsingRetriesIf_ReturnIsFalse(() =>
            {
                bool success = false;

                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = Http_Client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result)
                {
                    if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        response = parseResponseMethod(httpResponse);
                        success = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        failedReason = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
                        success = false;
                    }
                }

                return success;
            }, maxRetries, exponentialRetries, baseValue);

            if (!succeeded)
                throw new Exception(failedReason);
        }
        finally { Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear(); }

        return response;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Parse
    public T1 ParseToResponseContract<T1>(HttpResponseMessage httpResponse) where T1 : new()
    {
        T1 results = new T1();

        try
        {
            if (httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString().ToLower().Contains("application/json"))
            {
                string jsonResponse = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                using (MemoryStream jsonStreamResponse = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonResponse)))
                {
                    //DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings()
                    //{
                    //    //DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
                    //    UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true,
                    //    EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never
                    //};

                    DataContractJsonSerializer dcs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T1));
                    results = (T1)dcs.ReadObject(jsonStreamResponse);
                }
            }
        }
        finally { }

        return results;
    }
    #endregion
    #endregion


    #region Private Methods
    private void InitHttpClient()
    {
        if (Http_Client == null)
        {
            Http_Client_Handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() };

            Http_Client = new HttpClient(Http_Client_Handler);

            Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void Dispose()
    {
        if (Http_Client != null)
        {
            Http_Client.Dispose();

            Http_Client = null;
        }

        if (Http_Client_Handler != null)
        {
            Http_Client_Handler.Dispose();

            Http_Client_Handler = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Static Properties
    private static readonly IHttpFunctions mHttpFunctions = new HttpFunctions();

    public static IHttpFunctions InnerFunctions
    {
        get { return mHttpFunctions; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

---

Comment: The best choice is using ``IHttpClientFactory ``, because with singleton you don't notify with DNS changes on base address.

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad I am aware of the DNS issues related to this, but since I wish to centralize the "API Calling" functionality as much as possible in order so that I do not have to make repeated configures per application, I do not think that `IHttpClientFactory` is the ideal in this case :/

Comment: You can config ``IHttpClientFactory`` in your library and just call it from another project.